# Get historical currency rate via CURRENCYH shows error: The requested historical date is invalid or is in the future

Tags: numbers

From Apple Number’s [doc](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/functions/ffa3e86ad3f3/10.0/web/1.0), the formula `CURRENCYH` should return historical currency data.

> Examples
>
> =CURRENCYH(“USD”, “GBP”, 3, “18/04/2017”) returns £0.78, the lowest rate of exchange (“low” or 3) from the United States dollar (USD) to
>   Pounds sterling (GBP) on 18 April 2017.
>
> =CURRENCYH(“gbp”, “bmd”, “open”, “31/12/2015”) returns BMD1.48, the exchange rate from Pounds sterling (GBP) to the Bermudian dollar (BMD)
>   at the beginning of trading on 31 December 2015.
>
> =CURRENCYH(“usd”, “aud”, “close”, TODAY()-2) returns the exchange rate from United States dollars to Australian dollars (in AUD) at the close
>   of trading two days ago.

However, when I try it with `TODAY()-2` (writing as of 4 May 2020) and a couple of previous days, it shows the error **The requested historical date is invalid or is in the future.**

[image: formula]

[image: Today()-2]

I have to go back to `4 Apr 2020`, and the error message became **There is no historical data on the requested date. The next available is on 6/4/2020.**

[image: 4/4/2020]

After updating to `6 Apr 2020`, I managed to get the USDGBP rate and it is all available up until `17 Apr 2020`, then became unavailable.

[image: ok]

To summarise with a quick test from 1 Apr:

- 1-3 Apr are available
- 4-5 Apr are **NOT** available
- 6-17 Apr are available
- 18 Apr - 4 May are **NOT** available

It seems very unreliable for getting the currency rate for a specific date in Numbers. Is this expected, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of Numbers are you using? I tried getting USD to GBP from 1 April thru 4 May for 2017 thru 2020 for closing values using `Currencyh()`. All of the formulas have returned decent looking values for all dates except for weekends and 4 May 2020. I haven't tried this function before but it is possible that the recent historic data is always available with a bit of lag.  I have made this test using Numbers v6.1.

Comment: Numbers version 10.0, macOS 10.15.4

Comment: Also, IMO, partially not available and lag for two weeks doesn't make sense as Forex trades 24/7.

Comment: I haven’t traded a lot of FX but from what I know FX markets are closed on weekends. That might be the reason why there are no data over the weekends. I have an MBP that has Numbers v10.0. I will check if the file I have prepared that seems to be running OK on Numbers v6.1 is running OK also on v10.0 and let you know.

Comment: I ran the file with Numbers v10.0 and it is working alright on v10.0 as well. Data is not available for weekends as I explained before. Now the USD to GBP rate for 4 May 2020 is also being brought up on both versions. I guess it did not bring in 4 May 2020 before because I reckon the market was not closed when I ran the file on 4 May 2020 in the respective market about 12 hours ago. The file also runs OK on both versions for opening quotes for the same dates. Sorry that I can't tell you why it is not working on your computer as it does on the Macs I tried. Hope you figure it out soon.

Comment: Forex market is closed on weekends. So for APR 4-5 the error msg. is correct. Is the date range APR 6-17 continuously available (including weekends)? APR 18/19 is a weekend, so no data here again. Is the date range from APR 20 to MAY 4 continuously not available (including weekdays)? Btw., always error-handle financial data by encapsulating the formula with IFERROR.

Comment: I compared with Google sheet with the formula `=GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:USDGBP", "price", DATE(2020,4,4))`, and I managed to get the exchange rate from Apr to May, any reason for the discrepancy?. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Onvj1pO

Comment: @EES If you are asking about the existence of exchange rate parities over the weekends with Google Finance, it appears to me that the data for weekends from GF are bogus. For Saturdays, the parities seem to be nearly always the same as Friday closings. For Sundays, GF is probably showing (mistakenly) the Monday morning parities in Asian FX markets some of which are in time zones as much as 13 hours ahead of the US EST.

Answer (score 0):

It is phenomenally ugly, but I was able to get this to work with nested `iferror` checks that increment back a day at a time until there isn't an error.

`IFERROR(CURRENCYH("CAD","USD",0,A1),IFERROR(CURRENCYH("CAD","USD",0,A1−1),IFERROR(CURRENCYH("CAD","USD",0,A1−2),CURRENCY("CAD","USD",0)))`

(Here `A1` is the cell which contains the date.)

This version handles normal two-day weekends but then just defaults to the current exchange rates on three day weekends or other three-day periods when the exchange markets are closed. You could also have it error or do anything else, including looking back one more day, if you don't want that behaviour.

You could use `WORKDAY` to assist, with something like

```
CURRENCYH("CAD","USD",0,WORKDAY(A1,0))
```

but that doesn't know about market holidays (like today, a market closed day in the US and parts of Canada).